# Add space after the last item in Listbox in Ms. Access

Tags: ms-access, listbox

I am working on an MS. Access Database where I have list boxes that show items from a table through code. The List boxes don't display the blank/empty item after the last item of the list.

How can I make this blank item be displayed? Or is it possible to add a margin/padding after the last item? As in here [List with space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDXor.png)

See that the scroll reached the end of the list but no space appears. [List without space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peBZ8.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is dependent upon whether the height of the list box is evenly divisible by the line height of the items it contains.

If you adjust the height by small increments at a time, you will observe that the gap beneath the last element gradually increases until the list box height becomes divisible by the row height, and another row fills the empty space.

Comment: I opened the database on different computer machine, the space appears as I need. I played around with it on my computer, it shows when I make the window not maximized. Seems to be a bug!

Thank you for your input.